# Stop Observable.timer() inside takeUntil() manually

Tags: android, observable, rx-java, rx-java2

Case: Observing some items during next 5 seconds, but also I want manually to terminate getting items.

I have this code

```kotlin
private var disposable: Disposable? = null

...

observableThatHasToBeAliveAllTime
    .switchMap {
        observableThatEmitsItemOver5SecsWhenUpperObsEmits()
            .takeUntil(
                Observable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .also { disposable = it.subscribe() }
            )
            .switchMap { /* some work */ }
    }
    .subscribe { /* handle result */ }
```

and in other place I call `disposable?.dispose`, but takeUntil() keeps working

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

That `it.subscribe()` subscribes to `timer` completely separately from `takeUntil` and has no effect. Also `takeUntil` requires an `onNext` or `onComplete` signal from the other source thus dispose would not work as expected either.

You could use a separate subject with another `takeUntil` to stop the flow:

```kotlin
var stop = PublishSubject.create<Object>()

observableThatHasToBeAliveAllTime
    .switchMap {
        observableThatEmitsItemOver5SecsWhenUpperObsEmits()
            .takeUntil(
                Observable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            )
            .takeUntil(stop)
            .switchMap { /* some work */ }
    }
    .subscribe { /* handle result */ }

stop.onNext("Stop!");
```